# Is 在 optional in 你们明天在咖啡馆见面?

Tags: grammar, difference, sentence-structure

I found this two examples at the same Chinese lesson text, but it is not explained why 在 is omitted in one of them:

1. 你们明天在咖啡馆见面
2. 你们明天咖啡馆见面

Is 在 optional?

Comment: Usually it does not matter, might be better to include it though

Comment: Hopefully we can get answers which cite e.g. grammar textbooks.  "A random person on the Internet says so" is not a reliable answer.

Answer (score 1):

In is not necessary. In Chinese, prepositions can be omitted when they do not affect the understanding of the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but the probability to use 在 is much hight than without it. The reason is 咖啡馆 is a place and there is a verb phrase following it。actually， it is omitted because the information and word categories in the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Think you need 在

甲先生：我们明天在哪里见面？
乙女士：我们明天在咖啡馆见面吧。

Maybe two spies are listening to their controller.
Maybe there is a a coffee house called "Tomorrow". Still need 在

你们明天下午三点在“明天”那家咖啡馆见面！

Answer (score 0):

Adverb can be ignored if it will not lead to misunderstanding.
Here "在" is optional.

Answer (score 0):

It's not required but better if have. I've found a sentence on 汉语教程 第二册 下 like this: 她给我打了一个电话 ，请我到一家咖啡馆跟她见面 。

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).